# Installing Mapnik v.3.0.12 on Win 8 with Python 2.7

Tags: python, installation, mapnik

I've been trying to work on this for hours where I ended up having to download Python 2.7 Version but still no luck.

Following the installation tutorial from Git: [Mapnik Windows Installation](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/WindowsInstallation), most specifically paying attention to Step 3 where PATH and PYTHONPATH variables are instructed to be added.

Both my USER and SYSTEM PATH Variables have the following modification:

FROM `;C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\lib; C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\bin;` TO `;C:\mapnik-v3.0.12\lib; C:\mapnik-v3.0.12\bin;`

Both my USER and SYSTEM PYTHONPATH:

```
C:\mapnik-v3.0.12\python\2.7\site-packages;
```

Additionally ONLY in my SYSTEM PATH Variable, I appended:

```
C:\Python27\
```

When I tried to test `import mapnik` the common problem still occurs:

```
  >>> import mapnik
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mapnik
```

Again, every solution that I've read said to check my variables. I can't figure out why it won't import properly despite the path modifications.

Comment: Does it help if you set the path in your script itself (before importing ``mapnik``) like ``sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/mapnik-v3.x/lib')``? If so, your env variables are misconfigured.

Comment: No :( I guess I'm gonna try from scratch again. The problem still persists

Comment: If Windows is not extremely must, I recommend you using mapnik on linux because there are less issues with paths like in windows.

Comment: Sad to say I can't find a solution to this one. I'll try what you recommend @nurgasemetey

Comment: I am coming across this exact issue. Not sure what do.

Comment: So hey guys @DonnyV. I've resolved this issue. Make sure that you have downloaded the Windows 32 bit package if you're using Windows. The source doesn't include the path \python\2.7\site-packages.

Comment: @Reiion the 32bit version of python?

Comment: @DonnyV. yeah. then if you were like me, I downloaded the source. Don't. There's a separate Windows package in the download site that says Windows 32 bit package. Download that one and just downgrade your python to 32